# How can I use "cleartool merge" to merge from a checked out version on another branch

Tags: merge, clearcase, cleartool, vcs-checkout

I have file checked out in a view, on its default branch:

```
/main/pdb8.1/fq05-ae002.4/CHECKEDOUT
```

I have another view which creates a branch off of `fq05-ae002.4` called `ae002.4-test2`.
I have the file checked out in that view as well:

```
/main/pdb8.1/fq05-ae002.4/ae002.4-test2/CHECKEDOUT
```

I made a change to the checked-out version on the first branch, and want to merge it into the second branch.  I know how to do this via the VTree browser in Windows (and Unix), but I would like to know how to do it from the command line.  These files and vobs are large, and loading the VTree takes forever.
I already know how to do it if the file is checked in on the first branch (e.g. version 2):

```
ct merge -to myfile -insert -version /main/pdb8.1/fq05-ae002.4/2
ct mkhlink -unidir Merge /vobs/{vob}/path/to/myfile@@/main/pdb8.1/fq05-ae002.4/2 myfile
```

But I guess I'm not sure what to put in place of `/main/pdb8.1/fq05-ae002.4/2`.  The `CHECKEDOUT.464646` doesn't work.

Comment: Could you checkin your q05-ae002.4/CHECKEDOUT version first?

Comment: See comment on @Brian Cowan's answer.

Comment: Would merge work with `q05-ae002.4/LATEST`, in an attenmpt to reference the content of the source checkedout file?

Answer (score 0):

It is not generally possible to merge FROM a checked out version. If you can start both views and access the checked out version that way, you may be able to use the merge tool to merge them that way, providing the paths for the and from versions.

Is there some reason you can't check the source version in first?

Comment: I'd rather not check in the source version,.  It's kind of a weird situation.  I'm using the dest version for testing, and I had originally merged the souce into the destination for that purpose.  I suppose the right thing to do would be to check in the source, keep updating the destination, and then when it's done, I check that in and then merge back into the source.

Comment: But what's weirding me out is that I can do what I want to do in the VTree browser, but can't figure out how to do it from the command line.  I wish there was a way to see what it's doing behind the scenes.